# Looking for ICS information at common launch facilities

Tags: launch, launch-site

I'm doing some research on cyber threats to launch facilities, such as those against industrial control systems leveraged by a typical launch service provider.  Details of which types of systems are irrelevant for this study, just trying to get an idea of the type of systems found at sites.  Anyone know of good references?

Comment: What's ICS? Maybe best to avoid acronyms in titles.